# The program does not recognize the function oneTapClient.beginSignIn()

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create in my Android app login function with a Google account via Firebase (using the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCIfBbm06QM&t=1040s). Unfortunately, I have a problem because the program shows an error in the beginSignIn function in oneTapClient. Do I need to import this function into my file or implement something in Gradle?

[This is my code in GoogleAuthUiClient.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTkYj.png)

(I'm using jetpack compose) ;))

I tried to implement gradle from the guy's tutorial file and I tried to look for a solution on the internet.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle). It's a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to call [beginSignIn()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/identity/SignInClient#beginSignIn(com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.BeginSignInRequest)) function, the object on which you should call the function should be of type [SignInClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/identity/SignInClient) and not `SignInClientImpl`. As far as I can see in your picture, there is no inheritance relationship between these two classes, hence that red line.

To solve this, you should change the type of the object like this:

```
oneTapClient: SignInClient
```

And your error will go gone.